# Использование разных подходов к программированию

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Мне интересно, какой смысл использовать разные подходы к написанию кода, особенно когда есть ёмкие варианты кода. Зачастую пересматривается чужие коды я часто нахожу, что даже один и тот же человек использует в разных местах разные подходы:

Например:

```
BtnCommit.Enabled:=I>0;
```

Или

```
If I>0 then
BtnCommit.Enabled:=True
Else BtnCommit.Enabled:=False;
```

Второй подход это явно больше кода - так в чем смысл его использовать?

То же касается использования Датасетов например (FireDac в этом случае)

```
While not QryDocs.EoF do
```

Или

```
For I:=0 to QryDocs.RecordCount-1 do
```

Comment: This is mostly a matter of personal taste. Sometimes extra verbosity is for conveying deeper meaning too

Comment: @D-side Добрый вечер, прошу прощения, хотел сначала опубликовать на английском стэке, но там бан на вопросы у меня.

Comment: Оперативно отреагировали! Снял закрывашку. Будем надеяться, оставивший минус скоро пройдёт мимо ещё раз (но это вряд ли).

Comment: если вы первые 2 примера кода видите у одного человека, то скорее всего первый  (краткий) был написал позже. То есть знания и навыки за этот период несколько улучшились.

Answer (score 2):

В первом случае никакой разницы в плане скорости. Но в плане читабельности намного лучше 1й вариант. Смысла нет писать конструкцию с условием, когда вам в зависимости от результата нужно записать булевое значение в какую то переменную. Лучше использовать `BtnCommit.Enabled:= Условие;`. 
Во втором же случае, если вам нужен какой то счётчик, то лучше использовать второй вариант. Если же нет, то первый.

Comment: А во втором случае с while разве нельзя добавить счётчик и делать его инкремент?

Comment: @SovereignSun можно и жало молотку заточить на крест и заворачивать им шурупы, но лучше сразу использовать отвертку. Так и тут, нужен счетчик - берите цикл. Не нужен - берите while.

Answer (score 2):

1. Краткая запись булевых присвоений. Как верно заметили, новички чаще пишут по 2-му варианту. Это более многословная запись, и никакого смысла, кроме избыточной читаемости она не несет.
2. Способ итерирования. А вот тут небольшая разница есть. Обычно, при итерации по элементам датасета, вам не важно знать, на какой строке вы находитесь, а важно просто пройти от начала до конца по всем элементам:

   ```
   while not qry.Eof do
   ```

   Если же у вас будет итерация циклом, то вы добавляете новую сущность - итератор `I`, которым по сути не пользуетесь. Например, статические анализаторы вас предупредят о неиспользуемой переменной `I` в таком варианте:

   ```
   аor I := 0 to qry.RecordCount - 1 do
   ```